# Get value from another table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables A and B. I would like to fetch the value from Table B for each unique date for Table A.

As an example Suppose Below is the **Table A**. For the same Crawl_date it is having multiple data.

| Crawl_date | Seller A |
| --- | --- |
| 1/12/2022 | Hari |
| 1/12/2022 | Om |
| 1/12/2022 | Harry |
| 1/15/2022 | Harry |
| 1/15/2022 | Mat |
| 1/17/2022 | Kat |
| 1/17/2022 | Will |

Table B --

| Crawl_date | Value B |
| --- | --- |
| 1/12/2022 | 1 |
| 1/13/2022 | 2 |
| 1/14/2022 | 3 |
| 1/15/2022 | 4 |
| 1/16/2022 | 55 |
| 1/17/2022 | 66 |
| 1/18/2022 | 77 |

My Expectations are --

| Crawl_date | Value B |
| --- | --- |
| 1/12/2022 | 1 |
| 1/15/2022 | 4 |
| 1/17/2022 | 66 |

For each unique date in Table A, I would like to fetch the corresponding data from Table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a calculated table:

```
New Table = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table A', 'Table A'[Crawl_date]),
    "Value B", 
    VAR a = CALCULATE(MIN('Table A'[Crawl_date])) 
    RETURN CALCULATE(MIN('Table B'[Value B]), 'Table B'[Crawl_date] = a)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

step1. create relationship between table A and B in model view, it should be one-multiple relationship:

[image]

step2. create column in Table A with formula:

```
Value B = RELATED('Table B'[Value B])
```

[image]

step3. if you want to get a new table then create table with formula:

```
New table = summarize('Table A','Table A'[Crawl_date],'Table A'[Value B])
```

[image]